# JavaScript, how to limit todo list number?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was making a to-do list and I couldn't figure out how can I limit the number of creating li. I want to stop it from creating li when it reaches 4 li by not showing it on ul and stop submitting it. This is the one I wrote. If anyone can give me advice or ideas on how to solve this one. Thank you.

```
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const memo = document.querySelector('ul')

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    const line = document.ul.child

    if (line > 5) {
        e.preventDefault()
        ToDo()
        input.value = ""
    }
})

function ToDo() {
    if (input.value == '') {
        alert('please write')
    } else {
        const value = input.value
        const newList = document.createElement('li')
        newList.textContent = value
        memo.append(newList)
        const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
        newList.append(' ', ' ', deleteBtn)
        deleteBtn.textContent = "DELETE"
        console.log(newList)
    }
}

memo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName === 'BUTTON') {
        e.target.closest('LI').remove();
    }
})
```

whole code: [here](https://codepen.io/jujuju12/pen/MWrojJZ)

Comment: will you please tell me why you are using greater than condition here? accordingto your question it should be less than right?  if(line > 5){
        e.preventDefault()
        ToDo()
        input.value = ""
     }

Comment: I didn't realize that I used the wrong sign.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

This line`const line = document.ul.child` would give an error, as it is not valid way to query things from the DOM. Also `e.preventDefault()` shouldn't be in the `if` block even if it were correct. This would work:

```js
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const input = document.querySelector("input");
const memo = document.querySelector("ul");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const liNumber = document.querySelectorAll("ul li").length;

  if (liNumber < 4) {
    ToDo();
    input.value = "";
  } else {
    alert("Maximum number reached");
  }
});

function ToDo() {
  if (input.value == "") {
    alert("please write");
  } else {
    const value = input.value;
    const newList = document.createElement("li");
    newList.textContent = value;
    memo.append(newList);
    const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
    newList.append(" ", " ", deleteBtn);
    deleteBtn.textContent = "DELETE";
  }
}

memo.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    e.target.closest("LI").remove();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    83.2deg,
    rgba(150, 93, 233, 1) 10.8%,
    rgba(99, 88, 238, 1) 94.3%
  );
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Regular", "Lucida Grande",
    "Lucida Sans Unicode", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: #fbfbf2;
}
.option {
  margin-top: 4rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
#input {
  width: 400px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#submit {
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #5a189a;
  color: #fbfbf2;
}
#input,
#submit {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: none;
}
.lists {
  background-color: #efd9ce;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.memo {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
ul li {
  margin: 20px;
}
button {
  background-color: #5a189a;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #fbfbf2;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
  <div class="option">
    <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="enter a task" />
    <button type="submit" id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
  </div>
</form>
<div class="lists">
  <ul class="memo"></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great solution